# Is there a way to install an Haskell executable as a dependency?

Tags: haskell

I found myself writing Haskell commands based upon other commands provided by other Haskell packages, but i could not find a way to install an executable as a dependency.

As far as i could see, Cabal and Stack provide ways for a package to depend on a library, but not on an executable.

If i want to build upon the functionality already provided by another executable, the only way i know is to ask the users to install that other package as well. That also means that i cannot assume the executable is there or its version is the right one.

So is there a way for an Haskell package to depend on an executable provided by another package?

Comment: This seems to be doable with a `custom-setup` field in the cabal file. At least [that's what the gtk package does](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.14.10/gtk.cabal), which depends on executables from [gtk2hs-buildtools](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk2hs-buildtools).

Comment: This also requires some custom setup code to be written, right? It sounds like a solution, even though i thought there was a simpler way

Comment: There's also `build-tool-depends` field since `Cabal-2.0` : https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#pkg-field-build-tool-depends

Comment: so will executables added with `build-tool-depends` be available also at runtime, or only at compile time? if the first option holds, it feels like a different name would be more suited to the field